# name 'entry_widget' is not definied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i just writed a programm which should give me the ability to "lock" my screen with a window big as my screen resolution and can not be closed if right password is not given.
So my problem is:
I have a button on main window which creates the second window and widgets of it. And i have a second button on the second window which should get the given password prom the Entry widget on the second window which is created by the first button on the first window. 
And when i click the second button on the second window it can not get the text from the entry widget on the second window.

```
def locking():
    password_box["state"] = "disabled"
    true_password = password_box.get()
    lock = Tk()
    lock.configure(bg="grey")
    lock.geometry(resolution)
    lock.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    lock.resizable("False", "False")
    lock.overrideredirect(1)

    lock_password_box = Entry(lock, 
                              width="30",
                              justify="center",
                              show="*")
    unlock_button = Button(lock,
                           text="       Unlock       ",
                           command=unlocking)

    lock_password_box = Entry(lock,    # HERE THE WIDGET WHICH CAN NOT BE FOUND 
                              width="30",
                              justify="center", 
                              show="*")

    res_x_int = int(res_x)
    res_y_int = int(res_y)

    middle_x = res_x_int / 2
    middle_y = res_y_int / 2      

    middle_x_box = middle_x - 130
    middle_y_box = middle_y - 40

    middle_x_button = middle_x - 80
    middle_y_button = middle_y 

    lock_password_box.place(x=str(middle_x_box), y=(middle_y_box))
    unlock_button.place(x=str(middle_x_button), y=(middle_y_button)) 




def unlocking():
    given_password = lock_password_box.get()    # HERE I CALL IT

    if given_password.startswith("__commmand"):
        if given_password[11:] == "unlock":
            lock.destroy()
            password_box["state"] = "enabled"

        else:
            lock_password_box.insert("")

    elif given_password == true_password:
        lock.destroy()
        password_box["state"] = "enabled"

    else:
        lock_password_box.insert("") 

# AND FINALLY THE ERROR

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbilal25tr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mbilal25tr\Desktop\project.pyw", line 53, in unlocking
    given_password = lock_password_box.get()
NameError: name 'lock_password_box' is not defined
```

Script(not long): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2caa1PPqDe8NWR1aFYxd09tVzA

I really don't understand why this is happening. Please help if someone can. Thanks anyway.

Comment: All of your variables are local variables within ``locking()``.  They cease to exist the moment that function ends.

Comment: @jasonharper What should I do then please?

Comment: you can create this variables outside functions and they will be global - and then you can use keyword `global` in functions to inform functions to use external/global variable instead of creating local one.

Comment: or you can use `return lock_password_box` in `locking()` and `lock_password_box = locking()` and later `unlocking(lock_password_box)`

Comment: @furas I have tried the first already. Bu then it couldn't find the tk.lock because it's still in locking(). But I can't take it out so the button would be useless then.

Comment: @furas I tried the second alredy too but I wrote "global lock_password_box". It's didn't work. But I will try return because make more sense then mine lol. I will try it soon when I reach my pc again. Thanks for your answers...

Comment: question is where did you write `global lock_password_box` - you have to write it inside function `locking()` to inform function that you whan to use external variable instead of local one when you use `=` - in `lock_password_box = Entry(...)`. And you have to execute `locking()` before `unlocking()`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks @furas